# xpra and sudo / what is the difference between sudo and "being a user"

Tags: docker, sudo

I'm trying to create a docker image with `xpra` and `chrome` in it. As I also need to be able to use this base image to install further software I don't change the user at the end of the `Dockerfile`.

During a build I use this image for 2 purposes:
- build the final image
- use the base image to run `xpra` and `chrome` for build purposes

In the first occasion you need to be root, in the second occasion you need to be the chrome user. I tried to solve this by using sudo: (e.g. `sudo -i -u chrome xpra ...`, but this causes problems. If I change the base image to be the chrome user (`USER CHROME` in the Dockerfile), it works fine.

The full error I get:

```
2018-07-02 11:23:39,828 Error: cannot start the desktop server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xpra/scripts/server.py", line 1011, in run_server
    app.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xpra/server/server_base.py", line 119, in setup
    c.setup(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xpra/server/mixins/audio_server.py", line 55, in setup
    self.init_pulseaudio()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xpra/server/mixins/audio_server.py", line 117, in init_pulseaudio
    os.mkdir(self.pulseaudio_private_dir, 0o700)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/run/user/1000/xpra/pulse-:0'
2018-07-02 11:23:39,828 [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/run/user/1000/xpra/pulse-:0'
```

the `/run/user` directory doesn't exist in either of the images.

Comment: Possibly add your dockerfile as well to provide better background on the issue

Answer (score 1):

I worked out the issue in the end, and know why I forgot in the first place (I have been able to work on this really fragmented only. The Docker file contained: `ENV XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp`

Basicly redirecting the runtime directory, but sudo actually removes that environment variable.